# 1. How do I align all equations in column 2? 2. Also the left [ of my matrices is not appearing. How do I solve these 2 problems?

Tags: align, longtable, makecell

Below is the my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,openany]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1.2pt}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{color,fancyhdr}
\definecolor{mintbg}{rgb}{.63,.79,.95}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|p{3.7cm}|p{5cm}|p{4cm}|}
    \hline
        \bfseries A&\bfseries B&\bfseries C  \\ \hline \hline
    \endfirsthead
    \hline 
    \bfseries A&\bfseries B&\bfseries C  \\ \hline \hline
    \endhead
    \hline \multicolumn{3}{r}{\emph{Continued on next page}}
    \endfoot
    \hline
    \endlastfoot
    \rowcolor{mintbg}A&$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0
    \end{bmatrix}
    $$ &\Gape[6pt]{0} \\    
    \hline 
    \rowcolor{mintbg}B&$$B=\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 \\
        1 & 1
    \end{bmatrix}  $$& \Gape[6pt]{$ 1$} \\
    \hline
    \rowcolor{mintbg}C&  $$C=\begin{bmatrix}
        2& 2 \\
        2 & 2
    \end{bmatrix}  $$&\Gape[6pt]{$ 2$}
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

I am kindly requesting for assistance on the above 2 problems I mentioned.

Comment: What kind of alignment do you expect? currently all entries in the second column are vertically and horizontally centered in their respective cells.

Comment: I want all the equal signs in column 2 to be aligned

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not perfect, but if you are not too picky, the following solution should be acceptable:

[image]

In above table is considered `longtblr` table defined in the `tabularay` package. That equation are strict aligned at equal signs, is introduced new column for equations' parts before equals, where contents are right aligned:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,openany]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{mintbg}{rgb}{.63,.79,.95}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\DefTblrTemplate{middlehead,lasthead}{default}{Continued from previous page}
\DefTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{normal}{\scriptsize\textit{Continued on the next page}}
\SetTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{normal}
\begin{longtblr}[
  caption = {The Long Table Caption},
    label = {tab:longtblr},
                ]{width =140mm, % 127mm + 6*6pt ~ 140mm
                  hlines={1pt}, 
                  vline{1-2,4-5}={1pt}, 
                  colspec= {X[0.5,l] X[0.4,r] @{} X[0.6,l] X[1.2,l]}, 
                  column{2}={rightsep=4pt},
                  rowsep = {7pt},
                  row{1} = {abovesep=4pt, belowsep=4pt},
                  rows   = {mintbg},
                  row{1} = {font=\bfseries, white}
                 }
A   &   \SetCell[c=2]{c} B
            &               &   C   \\    
A   &   $A$ & $= \begin{bmatrix}
                0 & 0 \\
                0 & 0
            \end{bmatrix}$  &   0   \\
%
B   &   $B$ & $ = \begin{bmatrix}
                1 & 1 \\
                1 & 1
            \end{bmatrix}$  &  1   \\
%
C   &   $C$ & $ = \begin{bmatrix}
                2& 2 \\
                2 & 2
            \end{bmatrix}$  &   2   \\
\end{longtblr}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
corected is width of table. In the first solution I forgot to consider `\tabcolsep` in column width. Now is corrected, so the table now has the same width as is determined in the question.

Comment: How do I make the adjustments on the longtlbr that are equivalent to \begin{longtable}{|p{3.7cm}|p{5cm}|p{4cm}|} ?

Comment: @itc, it is already approximated. If you like to have exactly ratio between them, insert numbers in `p` columns into X columns, however, your third columns are replaced by two columns which sum of widths is equal to width of your second column. See, if `colspec= {X[3.7,l] X[2,r] @{} X[3,l] X[4,l]}, ` gives table design as you like to have.

Comment: Not yet. They must be increased again. But I dont know how to do that

Comment: @itc, why not? You should add more context to your table example, that it will be more clear in which ration the your second column had to be split in two columns. However, table has the same width as yours, Ratio of columns widths is determined by numbers in `X` columns. you may experiment with this numbers that you will get desired result.

Comment: \begin{longtable}{|p{3.7cm}|p{5cm}|p{4cm}|}  is wider than colspec= {X[3.7,l] X[2,r] @{} X[3,l] X[4,l]}. Please help on the adjustments

Comment: @itc, ups, at calculation of table width I forgot on `\tabcolsep` which are not considered in `X` columns. Corrected now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128233/discussion-between-itc-and-zarko).

Answer (score 0):

For the alignment, use `$A=\begin{bmatrix} ...\end{bmatrix}$` instead of `$$`.
The initial bracket is there (if u copy the output in generated document and paste it somewhere you will see that the bracket is there) but for some reason, the initial bracket took the color of the background. If you remove the rowcolor you will see it again.

Comment: Is there any way of making it visible? Besides if I use the $ instead of $$ my matrices will shrink.

Comment: Use $\displaystyle ... $.  The default for $...$ is \textstyle.